# Rectangle Ray Intersection

Tags: c#, .net, linear-algebra, raytracing

Im making a simple Ray Traycer in C#. And for my viewport I have a rectangle class.

```
public class Rectangle3D
{
    public readonly Point3D Point1;
    public readonly Point3D Point2;
    public readonly Point3D Point3;
    public readonly Point3D Point4;

    public Rectangle3D(Point3D point1, Point3D point2, Point3D point3, Point3D point4)
    {
        this.Point1 = point1;
        this.Point2 = point2;
        this.Point3 = point3;
        this.Point4 = point4;
    }

    public Point3D FindCrossPoint(Ray ray)
    {
        //Intersection
    }
```

how would I go about writing this function. Help is much appreciated.
P.S Point3D has all the needed functions. Such as cross,normalize etc...

Comment: I tried representing a rectangle through triangles and then testing collision but that way to complicated really fast. And I didn't say for you guys to write the code I asked, how should I write it. Trust me I'm not trying to be lazy even if it does look like that. I'm also really naïve to this field. Thank you.

Comment: I did line-line intersection in 3D. But I don't understand how to do this for a rectangle

Comment: OK, can you intersect a line with a *plane* in 3D?

Comment: That I don't know how to do. Sorry if I'm being annoying.

Comment: okay... so I understand how to solve the equation above. But how do you find a plane from 4 points?
 P.S Never learned this in school. I'm just 15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, let's put this in the form of an answer instead of all those comments.

Break your problem down into sub-problems:

1) Find the plane that the rectangle lies on, in the form `Ax+By+Cz+D=0` Two methods:

Method one:

- Find the equations of two orthogonal lines; the edges of the rectangle will be orthogonal by definition.
- Given two orthogonal lines, figure out how to get the equation of the plane the lines define, in the form `Ax+By+Cz+D=0`.

Some hints here:

- Suppose the two orthogonal lines were both going through the origin. Make them vectors. What is the meaning of the cross product of those two vectors?
- What is the relationship between the cross product vector and the plane you're seeking? Specifically, what is the relationship between the cross product vector, and the constants A, B and C?

Method two:

- Pick three of the points on the rectangle that do not lie in a line; obviously any three corners will do.  Substitute those points in for x, y, z in `Ax+By+Cz+D=0` to make three new equations; solve those equations for A, B, C and D.

2) Once you have the equation of the plane, work out the intersection of the plane with the ray.

3) Now that you have the intersection point -- if it exists, remember, the ray might be parallel to the plane or might be entirely in the plane -- check to see if the intersection point is inside the rectangle.

- Hint: this is a special case of the more general problem of "is this point inside a polygon".